# Getting nested data from firebase database by "onchildchanged" and "onchildadded" returns something unrecognizable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: console_screenshot]
 This is the screenshot of the console that displays the output i.e. the child added in the messages directory of one of the users.
Also , it must be noticed that I have displayed very short portion of console, as the console is displaying similar output for each and every messages. If more screenshots are required for clarification, please tell me, I will add them!
This is my json code:

```
{
"Tf42glUiUvbF1yGMX1CseYD6EVC3" : {
  "intents" : {
    "intentFields" : "",
    "intentName" : ""
  },
  "messages" : {
    "-KViVgc7ZG051eMXP0-5" : {
      "name" : "Ed",
      "photoUrl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-512.png",
      "text" : "Hello, I'm Ed, your personal assistant cum friend",
      "timeStamp" : "1476880306"
    },
    "-KW3C8azYBP_-BIlWmNV" : {
      "name" : "Aakash Bansal",
      "photoUrl" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-oQyA4HXVycc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAHKo/Ov0A0p0LjiY/s96-c/photo.jpg",
      "text" : "hi",         //this is the message displayed in the console above.
      "timeStamp" : "1478613047"
    }
  }
},
"gFiPrpHcHeMkqG2tGUi1aolIR3x1" : {
  "intents" : {
    "intentFields" : "",
    "intentName" : ""
  },
  "messages" : {
    "-KViVgc7ZG051eMXP0-5" : {
      "name" : "Ed",
      "photoUrl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-512.png",
      "text" : "Hello, I'm Ed, your personal assistant cum friend",
      "timeStamp" : "1476880306"
    }
  }
}
```

}

This is my node.js code:

```
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
    snapshot.ref.child("messages").on("child_added", function(itemSnapshot) {
        var mytemp = itemSnapshot.child("text");
    console.log(mytemp);
  });
});
```

**NOTE** I viewed some similar questions on stackoverflow but when I implemented them, I came to know that they belonged to the outdated version of the firebase and didn't work in this current version.
**EDIT** By using the following code, I'm now getting `null` for each child added. Also, I want to ask how to get the parent's or user's id whose child has changed.
The code is:

```
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
//using limitToLast(1) to get last value only
snapshot.ref.child("messages").orderByKey().limitToLast(1).once("value", function(itemSnapshot) {
    var mytemp = itemSnapshot.child("text").val();
console.log(mytemp);
```

});
});

[image: console.png] This is the screenshot of console after using this code
I got my answer for the aove question, but only remaining doubt is how to get the parent of the node whose child has changed?

Please feel free to ask for any more clarification if and when needed
Thanks!!

Comment: In future questions, please don't post images of text, such as the JSON structure of your database. Instead, post the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: OK sir, @FrankvanPuffelen, I'll take care!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, sir does the solution of this problem exists or is it impossible to get such result from this type of database using FireBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for this:

```
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
    snapshot.child("messages").forEach(function(itemSnapshot) {
        var mytemp = itemSnapshot.child("text").val();
        console.log(mytemp);
    });
});
```

Comment: sir, I think this code of yours is unable to handle nested queries in the database, as I am not getting any output by using this code. I think we should use one more listener inside the `ref.on("child_changed",...` listener

Comment: Are you changing the child in question?

Comment: yes sir, I'm changing the child. whenever a user sends a message, a child is added to the `messages` directory of the user and as a result the child changes.

Comment: See http://jsbin.com/kexano/edit?js,console. It changes one of the messages and through that fires the `child_changed` event. This in turn prints the text of the two messages you provided.

Comment: sir Got it! Thanks, and one last question, how do I get the id of the node whose child has changed.i.e. parent of the node in which message has added for eg: I should get `Tf42glUiUvbF1yGMX1CseYD6EVC3` when a message is sent by the user with id `Tf42glUiUvbF1yGMX1CseYD6EVC3`